# What are the mean and variance?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The Fahrenheit-Celsius conversion formula is $F= \frac{9}{5}C+32$. Suppose the temperature measured in Celsius has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. What are the mean and variance of the temperature in Fahrenheit degrees?

$$\mu = \frac{x_1+...x_i}{n}   \sigma^2= \frac{(x_1-\mu)^2+(x_2-\mu)^2...}{n}$$

Essentially I have to pick some values for $C$ and convert them to $F$ and just find the $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ right?

I'll input the values later on, but is my thinking correct for this question?

Comment: Hint:  If $X$ is any random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, what is the mean and variance of $aX +b$?  No need to pick any values...

Comment: Try and find expressions for: $$\operatorname*{E}[aC+b]=\cdots$$ And: $$\operatorname*{Var}[aC+b]=\cdots$$

Comment: What @projectilemotion says (and lulu as well) is that you haven't to refer to data (this would be a statistical approach): your question is purely probabilistic, and uses probability theorems like linearity of mathematical expectation $E(aX+b)=aE(X)+b$ etc.

Comment: So $\mu = E\{X\}$ and $\sigma ^2 =Var(X)$. and $Var(X)= E\{x^2\}-E\{X\}^2 = E\{(X-E\{X\})^2\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
Rather than picking random values of $C$, try to use the following properties of expectation and variance:

---

For a random variable $X$, we have:
$$\operatorname*{E}[aX+b]=a\cdot \operatorname*{E}[X]+b$$
And:
$$\operatorname*{Var}[aX+b]=a^2\cdot \operatorname*{Var}[X]$$

---

If you want to see a derivation of each, see [here](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~rosario/classes/11F/100a-1ab/100aHW5Soln.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjA0vXg8cTSAhVMuBoKHb2qCgMQFgglMAE&usg=AFQjCNGnmco2wP_PK6HqLVCAd3jK-pOKSg).

Comment: Okay, so I know that $Var(X)=E\{(X-E\{X\})^2\}$ then $Var[aX+b]=a^2*E\{(X-E\{X\})^2\}$?

Comment: Well, yes but it is not very relevant in this case. For example, to find the mean, you have your function $F=\frac{9}{5}C+32$ (Therefore $a=\frac{9}{5}$ and $b=32$). Therefore, the expectation of $F$ (The mean as well in this case) is given by: $$\operatorname*{E}[F]=\frac{9}{5}\operatorname*{E}[C]+32=\frac{9}{5}\mu+32$$
Can you proceed with finding the variance of $F$?

Comment: Would it be $Var[F]=\frac{81}{25}*Var[C] = \frac{81}{25} \sigma ^2$

Comment: @Killercamin Yes, you are right.

Comment: What other calculation am I supposed to do now? Or is that everything?

Comment: Well, normally that should be everything. You are given the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, so the question seems like they are expecting answers in terms of these. You cannot obtain values for $\mu$ or $\sigma$ since you aren't given a set of data.

Comment: Oh i see, but if they did give some data, we would just calculate for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.